# AWS: How to force stop creating DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

After running: $`aws dynamodb delete-table --table-name Listing-cmycl8n047yb70n704m804-react`

I'm getting this error: `An error occurred (ResourceInUseException) when calling the DeleteTable operation: Attempt to change a resource which is still in use: Table is being created: MY_TABLE_NAME`

The empty table has been creating for the last hour.

How can I force delete a table that is still creating?

Comment: You can't, and there's currently an incident in us-east-1 causing this: https://status.aws.amazon.com

Answer (score 0):

ResourceInUseException
The operation conflicts with the resource's availability. For example, you attempted to recreate an existing table, or tried to delete a table currently in the CREATING state.